# Matrix of the operator $A(x,y)=(y-x+iy,x-2y-ix)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I got an operator $A: \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ given as $A(x,y)=(y-x+iy,x-2y-ix)$

and I want to represent it as a matrix, so I could find then the orthonormal basis to which would have this operator a diagonal matrix form.

But I am not sure how to put it into the matrix, it confuses me:

$$
   A= \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 -i  \\
     1+i & -2 \\
      \end{pmatrix}
$$
 or

$$
   A= \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 +i  \\
     1-i & -2 \\
      \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The second one is the answer.

Comment: It depends on notation.  Let $M_A$ be the associated matrix.  If the output of $A$ is a row vector (as given) the option one is right as 
$$ A(1,0)=(-1,1-i)=(1,0)M_A=(1,0)\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 -i  \\
     1+i & -2 \\
      \end{pmatrix}.$$
Otherwise option two is the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A(1,0)=(-1,1-i)$ and $A(0,1)=(1+i,-2)$, the second option is the correct one.